# CSS link elements with no required type attribute

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

My FireFox HTML validator add-on always flags SO with a couple of warnings one of which is that the CSS link elements in the head don't have the required type attribute (type="text/css"). Is there a reason for this?

Also badge names with & characters don't seem to be HTML encoded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> CSS link elements in the head don't have the required type attribute (type="text/css")

It's not required according to the w3c validator:

http://validator.w3.org/check

I am inclined to favor that over a random add-in..

> badge names with & characters don't seem to be HTML encoded.

<s>possible, since I don't think many have & (strunk & white?), and we might want to fix that bug. Can you cite HTML source?</s>

Fixed, In a gross oversight, we weren't encoding badge names or descriptions. I blame me.

Comment: You're correct the add-on indicated it as a warning but http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#edef-LINK states that it's not required.

I noticed the & issue first on the recent badges section on the home page and also on the badge page itself http://stackoverflow.com/badges/12/strunk-white within the title and again further down the page.

Answer (score 1):

First off, CSS `<link>` don't actually need the type field in the tag.

But really, the most common answer to these sorts of questions is that perfectly valid HTML and CSS (even though in this case it is valid) is not a high priority because no one benefits (compared to something like new features) from it.

Comment: WONT SOMEONE THINK ABOUT THE POOR VALIDATORS??!?!

Comment: I, for one, welcome our new, non validating web developers.

Comment: Meet the new web developers, same as the old web developers...

Comment: What I ment was that, on the grand scale, perfectly valid HTML+CSS is not that important compared to new features. Of course, I still believe web developers should be striving for validity...